# Order Data table based on Category in R

Tags: r

I have a data table that I created in R to compare the percentage between a population and sample. Here is the script I created for the table:

```
team_pop <- team_new %>% 
  group_by(degree) %>%
  count() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(pop = n/sum(n)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(pop)) %>%
  adorn_totals()

team_sample <- sample_final %>% 
  group_by(degree) %>%
  count() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(sam = n/sum(n)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(sam)) %>%
  adorn_totals()


datatable(
  team_pop %>%
    select(-n) %>%
  left_join(team_sample %>%
              select(degree, 
                     sam), 
            by = "degree"),
  rownames = FALSE,
  colnames = c(
    "Degree"= "degree",
    "Population" = "pop",
    "Sample" = "sam"), 
  options = list(info = FALSE, 
                 paging = FALSE,
                 searching = FALSE)
  ) %>%
  formatPercentage(2, digits = 0) %>%
  formatPercentage(3, digits = 0)
```

Here is what the data looks like:

| Degree | Population | Sample |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Medium | 45% | 43% |
| Low | 35% | 37% |
| High | 20% | 20% |

But this is how I want me data to be ordered in my data table:

| Degree | Population | Sample |
| --- | --- | --- |
| High | 20% | 20% |
| Medium | 45% | 43% |
| Low | 35% | 37% |

Just wondering if someone could please help me order my categories based on the Degree column from High to Low. I have tried the R function "sort" using the formula below, but it still orders my data based on the highest number first:

```
team_pop <- team_new %>% 
  group_by(degree) %>%
  count() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(pop = n/sum(n)) %>% 
  sort(degree, degreasing = FALSE) %>%
  adorn_totals()

team_sample <- sample_final %>% 
  group_by(degree) %>%
  count() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(sam = n/sum(n)) %>% 
  sort(degree, degreasing = FALSE) %>%
  adorn_totals()

datatable(
  team_pop %>%
    select(-n) %>%
  left_join(team_sample %>%
              select(degree, 
                     sam), 
            by = "degree"),
  rownames = FALSE,
  colnames = c(
    "Degree"= "degree",
    "Population" = "pop",
    "Sample" = "sam"), 
  options = list(info = FALSE, 
                 paging = FALSE,
                 searching = FALSE)
  ) %>%
  formatPercentage(2, digits = 0) %>%
  formatPercentage(3, digits = 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your degree variable a factor and then arrange based on degree.

```
team_pop <- team_pop %>% 
  mutate(Degree=factor(Degree, levels = c("High", "Medium", "Low"))) %>% 
  arrange(Degree)
```